# editing string using sed or grep

Tags: unix, grep, sed, aix

first of all please execuse my ignorance on UNIX. I am quite new.

I have lot many sql files that contains following string

```
${DB_USERNAME}.${TABLE_NAME}
```

Can anyone please tell me how could I change it in each file so that it remains only

```
${TABLE_NAME}
```

I have tried following pattern of sed.

```
sed 's/^[^\.]\+\.//'
```

But it returns only ".".

Please tell me whole combination of grep and sed.

I need to change files directly. As I think we should pipe output of grep to sed. remember I am on AIX

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why so complicated? If you only want to remove the specific part:

```
sed 's/${DB_USERNAME}.//g' < input-file > output-file
```

If you want to go with something like your original expression:

```
sed 's/^[^\.]*\.//g' < input-file > output-file
```

Comment: Thanks. that works but I need to change files directly. As I think we should pipe output of grep to sed.

Comment: If you need to change the file directly use in-place editing: `sed -i '' -e 's/…//g' input-file` or `sed -i -e 's/…//g' input-file` depending on your sed version.

Comment: I am on AIX.:(..

Comment: If your `sed` does not support in-place editing, simply use an intermediate file. Or use `sponge` from [Moreutils](https://joeyh.name/code/moreutils/) with `sed -e … file | sponge file`.